# A challenging binomial sum arising from the product of two Bessel functions $J_{\nu}(x)J_{\mu}(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, bessel-functions

I am trying to prove that the series expansion of product of two Bessel functions of the first kind around $x=0$ is given by:
$$
J_{\nu}(x)J_{\mu}(x) = \sum_{r=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^r \Gamma(\mu+\nu+2r+1)}{r! \Gamma(\nu+r+1)\Gamma(\mu+r+1)\Gamma(\mu+\nu+r+1)}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{\mu+\nu+2r} \tag{1}
$$
where $\nu, \mu\in \mathbb{R}$.

My approach is to multiply the series expansions of the individual Bessel functions and rearrange the terms in order to obtain (1).
$$
J_{\nu}(x)J_{\mu}(x) = \left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n }{n! \Gamma(n+\nu+1)}\left(\frac{x}{2} \right)^{\nu+2n}\right) \left(\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^m }{m! \Gamma(m+\nu+1)}\left(\frac{x}{2} \right)^{\nu+2m} \right)
$$
With some effort, I managed to reduce the above equation to:
$$
J_{\nu}(x)J_{\mu}(x) = \sum_{r=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^r }{r! \Gamma(\nu+r+1)\Gamma(\mu+r+1)}c_r \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{\mu+\nu+2r} \tag{2}
$$
where $c_r$ is defined as:
$$c_r = \sum_{n=0}^r \binom{r}{n} \left\{\prod_{i=r-n+1}^r  (\nu+i)\right\} \left\{\prod_{j=n+1}^r (\mu+j)\right\}$$

So, it turns out that to prove (1), we need to prove that:
\begin{align*}
c_r&= (\mu+\nu+2r)(\mu+\nu+2r-1)\cdots (\mu+\nu+r+1)\\
&= \frac{\Gamma(\mu+\nu+2r+1)}{\Gamma(\mu+\nu+r+1)} \tag{3}
\end{align*}
For small values of $r$, one can verify that (3) is indeed correct. One way to proceed would be to use induction on $r$. So far I have been unsuccessful with that. I would really grateful if someone could provide an elementary proof of equation (3). Maybe there's a combinatorial interpretation that I am unable to understand. Any references/suggestions related to this problem are also welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First recall that $a^{\overline{b}}=a(a+1)\cdots (a+b-1)$ is the definition of the **rising factorial.** Notice, furthermore, that your identity can be rewritten as
$$\sum _{n=0}^r\binom{r}{n}(\nu +r-n+1)^{\overline{n}}(\mu +n+1)^{\overline{r-n}}=(\mu +\nu+r+1)^{\overline{r}}.$$
To take out the $n's$ inside the monomials notice that $(a-n+1)^{\overline{n}}=(a)^{\underline{n}}$ (here $a^{\underline{n}}$ is called the **falling factorial** defined as $a(a-1)\cdots (a-n+1)$) and so $(\nu +r-n+1)^{\overline{n}}=(\nu+r)^{\underline{n}}$ and $(\mu +n+1)^{\overline{r-n}}=(\mu +r)^{\underline{r-n}}$ so your left hand side becomes
$$\sum _{n=0}^r\binom{r}{n}(\nu +r)^{\underline{n}}(\mu +r)^{\underline{r-n}}=(\nu +\mu+2r)^{\underline{r}}=(\nu +\mu +2r-r+1)^{\overline{r}},$$
where the intermediate step is the binomial theorem for falling factorials.

Comment: Thanks! I had never heard of the binomial theorem for falling factorials. Is there a good reference that you could point me to? Also, do you know if there is a multinomial version of this theorem as well?

Comment: Sure, i think this binomial theorem is general in the context of Sheffer sequences. In the particular case of falling and rising factorials probably any book with a section in finite calculus should have it. Try "A course in enumeration" of M. Aigner. Now, the multinomial version it should be cause multinomial is doing binomials in sequence, no?